# R table only has values when changing how to have all values without for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Data table is to be read by a human so it only shows the values in the first 2 columns when the value changes to make it easier to read.

The only way I have found to resolve this is by using a for loop and checking for the empty value and referencing the value from the previous row.

Example table

```
   Col.a Col.b Col.c Col.d Col.e Col.f
1     XX  XXXX  BBBB  CCCC  DDDD     1
2      Â     Â     Â     Â     Â     Â
3     YY  YYYY  BBBB  DDDD  FFFF     1
4      Â     Â  CCCC  EEEE   GGG     2
5     VV  VVVV     Â     Â     Â     3
6      Â     Â     Â     Â     Â     Â
7     CC   CCC  CCC1  DDDD  DDDD     1
8      Â     Â  CCC2  EEEE  EEEE     1
9      Â     Â  CCC3  1111  1123     3
10    CC   CCC     Â     Â     Â     5
11     Â     Â     Â     Â     Â     Â
```

Sample code to create dataframe, drop empty/subtotal rows and replace values with previous for columns 1-2

```
dftest <- 
  structure(list(Col.a = c("XX", "Â", "YY", "Â", "VV", "Â", "CC", 
  "Â", "Â", "CC", "Â"), Col.b = c("XXXX", "Â", "YYYY", "Â", "VVVV", 
  "Â", "CCC", "Â", "Â", "CCC", "Â"), Col.c = c("BBBB", "Â", "BBBB", 
  "CCCC", "Â", "Â", "CCC1", "CCC2", "CCC3", "Â", "Â"), Col.d = c("CCCC", 
  "Â", "DDDD", "EEEE", "Â", "Â", "DDDD", "EEEE", "1111", "Â", "Â"
  ), Col.e = c("DDDD", "Â", "FFFF", "GGG", "Â", "Â", "DDDD", "EEEE", 
  "1123", "Â", "Â"), Col.f = c("1", "Â", "1", "2", "3", "Â", "1", 
  "1", "3", "5", "Â")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -11L))


#drop "Â" in col.c as only reason is empty row or subtotal row which is not needed
dftest <- dftest[!dftest$Col.c == "Â",]

for (i in 1:nrow(dftest)) {
  if (dftest$Col.a[i] == "Â") {
      dftest$Col.a[i] = dftest$Col.a[i-1]
  }
  if (dftest$Col.b[i] == "Â") {
    dftest$Col.b[i] = dftest$Col.b[i-1]
  }
}
```

Output from the above code is what I want, can it be done without the for loop as some of the tables are big and there are a lot of them.

```
  Col.a Col.b Col.c Col.d Col.e Col.f
1    XX  XXXX  BBBB  CCCC  DDDD     1
3    YY  YYYY  BBBB  DDDD  FFFF     1
4    YY  YYYY  CCCC  EEEE   GGG     2
7    CC   CCC  CCC1  DDDD  DDDD     1
8    CC   CCC  CCC2  EEEE  EEEE     1
9    CC   CCC  CCC3  1111  1123     3
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `case_when` on each column separately and then do a `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
dftest %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(. == "Â" ~ lag(.), 
           TRUE ~ .))) %>%
   distinct %>% 
   filter(across(everything(), ~ . != "Â"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accumulate` from `purrr` for a recursive calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dftest %>%
  filter(Col.c != 'Â') %>%
  mutate(across(c(Col.a, Col.b), 
         ~accumulate(., ~if_else(.y == 'Â', .x, .y)))) -> result

result

#  Col.a Col.b Col.c Col.d Col.e Col.f
#1    XX  XXXX  BBBB  CCCC  DDDD     1
#2    YY  YYYY  BBBB  DDDD  FFFF     1
#3    YY  YYYY  CCCC  EEEE   GGG     2
#4    CC   CCC  CCC1  DDDD  DDDD     1
#5    CC   CCC  CCC2  EEEE  EEEE     1
#6    CC   CCC  CCC3  1111  1123     3
```